# Export Angular JQLite as $/jQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I occasionally find plugins that try to detect if JQuery is present, or might have 1-2 lines of code that uses `$`. I am wondering if it's possible to make Angular's JQLite available outside of angular apps somehow?  My first tries of simply seeing if JQLite was available did not work. Basically I would like either the variable `$` or `jQuery` to be available anywhere (or at least within my ng-app area) to see if it contains enough functionality to let these jquery plugins/code work.

Here's the source https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/jqLite.js

Comment: Do you want to be able to use jqLite with or without Angular as a dependency?

Comment: @MichaelBenford I have Angular loaded, I would like to expost jqLite as a standalone object I can use for quick one liners or too make some existing code happy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, you can, but it almost certainly won't help.

If you wanted to "export" it, you'd simply need to add this after the Angular JavaScript is loaded:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = angular.element;
```

Now calling `$()` or `jQuery()` will run `jqLite`.  <strike>Here's why it most likely won't work: `jqLite` doesn't support selectors, meaning you can't do</strike>

```
angular.element('.foo').html();
```

You'll just get an error stating that *Selectors not implemented*.

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xGQeD/) showing it working when used on elements directly, but failing with the selector.

---

#### Edit

Based on Yashua's suggestion below, here's an [update using his trick to enable selectors](http://jsfiddle.net/Zpcuk/).  It's a nice trick/hack if jqLite is good enough.

---

Personally, I don't agree that you should just include jQuery.  It's another large library to depend on, and if you are only performing a couple of one-liners, you should be able to integrate them into Angular directly using proper directives.  I'd take the time to see if you can rewrite the existing code.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I think this can be expanded to cover a bit more functionality. Here's a simple proof of concept that can select classes/id: http://jsfiddle.net/cyberwombat/R7mTq/1/